# CoreWebView2 WebResourceRequested redirect url SetHeader cookie not set

Tags: redirect, cookies, webview2

I use WebView2 to login into a website and set the session cookies for each request inside `WebResourceRequested` with code:

```
 wvBrowser.CoreWebView2.CookieManager.DeleteAllCookies();
 e.Request.Headers.SetHeader("Cookie", cookieshere);
```

The website I use it for has a couple of 302 redirects and the code above used to work, but since a few days my cookies aren't set on redirects. The initial request has the Cookie header, but the redirected request which still goes through `WebResourceRequested` doesn't have any cookies, this causes my session to expire. This is also the case on other websites if I test it. Is this normal behavior?

The redirect url is on the same host.

Tried settings cookies with AddOrUpdateCookie but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to make it work with `CreateCookie` and `AddOrUpdateCookie`

Comment: Hello. Can you please update the code in order to explain how you did it ?